# TCP Listener Doesnt Work In Debug Mode (Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, console-application

I'm making a tcp listener for my one of my projects and for whatever reason when i run the debug version it doesnt work but when i release and build it, it works fine which is really inconvenient for debugging purposes. I went to the build properties and the debug and release builds were identical anyone know whats going on here?

The listener is a windows console

Edit:
The debug version runs just doesnt detect connections but my release version does

Here's my code for handling connection 
SERVER:

```
    private void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        Socket socket;
        try
        {
            socket = server.EndAccept(ar);

        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException)
        {
            return;
        }
        userList.Add(new Users(socket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString(), socket));
        Log.Success("Client Connected!");
        sendAdminsLog("GREEN " + "Client Connected!");
        socket.BeginReceive(g_buffer, 0, g_buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), socket);
        server.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), null);
    }
```

CLIENT:

```
    Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    client.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("73.73.34.126"), 1234);//IPAddress.Loopback, 1234);
```

Comment: "*for whatever reason*", we have no idea what you have done, how your projects are configured, how you are testing this, what you are seeing, what error messages you are getting... Maybe you can create a minimal reproducible example (the smallest amount of code possible to verify and test your results), also read the help on asking a question, as this was fairly low quality

Comment: lol it was to emphasis my confusion as to why my debug version doesnt listen for connections and my release does

Comment: How do you start the debug/release mode apps? F5 and CTRL+F5? Both with F5? Does debug build with ctrl+F5 works?

Comment: No it runs but doesnt detect connections

Comment: If you are picking some parameters from app.config file then please make sure you have one app.config in solution OR both config files should have similar values (which is possible if you have more than one projects in one solution).

Answer (score 0):

It appears windows firewall would sometimes block the port, disabling it fixed it